# Problem adding a new record in my Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Freshsmvvm in my project and I want to display a list of operations,

**this is my method from the crud**

```
public List<Operation> GetAll()
{
    try
    {
       return connection.Table<Operation>().ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       StatusMessage = $"Error: {ex.Message}";
    }
    return null;
}
```

**In my viewModel i'm have a list and a method to obtain the saved records**

```
private List<Operation> _listOp;
public List<Operation> ListOp
{
      get { return _listOp; }
      set
      {
          _listOp = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged();
      }
}

private void GetOp()
{
    ListOp = App.OperationRepository.GetAll();
}
```

```
*add the GetOp method in the constructor to load in the collectionview*
public override void Init(object initData)
{
      GetOp();
}
```

What happens is that the list does not update, I have to close the application and when I open it again, the entered record appears.

[This is the list without adding a new record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMTcz.jpg)

[This is the list with a log after restarting the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUcWj.jpg)

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted shows how you add a new record.  Are you calling `GetOp` again after every new record is added?  The DB does not have any mechanism to update the UI when a record is added - you have to trigger that yourself.

Comment: Oh! the method that adds a record to the database if I have it, I forgot to add it inside this question.

I will try what you said, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method OnAppearing() to refresh your list.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    ListOp = App.OperationRepository.GetAll();
}
```